# Adding authentication to Jitsi Meet

Tags: jitsi, jitsi-meet

I would like to add the ability to only allow authenticated users to create a conference in Jitsi Meet. I see the external API's jwt param, config.tokenAuthUrl and the [lib-jitsi-meet tokens document](https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/tokens.md) but I'm very confused on how to put it all together.

Right now, my workflow is as follows:

1. User logs in with Google via custom app.
2. User is redirected to a new Jitsi conference with a jwt parameter derived from the Google login information.

Where I'm stuck is validating this token, and how to set it up to validate. What configuration needs made? What type of response should the tokenAuthUrl application be returning for valid/invalid JWTs?

Answer (score 1):

these changes should be made in `/etc/prosody/conf.avail/[your-hostname].cfg.lua`

a) Enable authentication on your main domain:

```
VirtualHost "jitsi-meet.example.com"
authentication = "internal_plain"
```

Source: https://github.com/jitsi/jicofo

Answer (score 0):

In Jitsi there are two types of authentication. One is `token-based` authentication and another one is `password-based` authentication. If you need to dynamically change permission on users then you have to go with `token-based` authentication. 
If you want to customize `token-based` authentication then you have to write custom prosody modules for that purpose.